# How can I resize a user control designer to fit control in it?

Tags: c#, winforms

I created a new user control and added to it's designer a pictureBox.

This is a screenshot of the user control designer with the pictureBox

[User Control designer with pictureBox in the middle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pALE.jpg)

Then I added this code to the user control

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Extract
{
    public partial class Slider : UserControl
    {
        public float Height;
        public float Min = 0.0f;
        public float Max = 1.0f;

        private float defaultValue = 0.1f;

        public Slider()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            
        }

        private void sliderControl_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            float bar_size = 0.45f;
            float x = Bar(defaultValue);
            int y = (int)(sliderControl.Height * bar_size);

            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.DimGray, 0, y, sliderControl.Width, y / 2);
        }

        private float Bar(float value)
        {
            return (sliderControl.Width - 24) * (value - Min) / (float)(Max - Min);
        }
    }
}
```

Then when I drag the control to form1 designer from the toolbox :

[The control in form1 designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2llnD.jpg)

The problem is when I try to resize the control in form1 designer I want to see only the pictureBox without the control around it. but when I resize it the pictureBox move down too much and then gone inside :

[Resized the control in form1 designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AB2Xx.jpg)

And if I resize the control size in the user control designer it self to fit the pictureBox size then when dragging it in form1 designer I don't see the pictureBox at all.  I need to resize it to see the pictureBox.

There is no dynamic resize I think.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is working very nice.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Extract
{
    public partial class Slider : UserControl
    {
        public float Height;
        public float Min = 0.0f;
        public float Max = 1.0f;

        private float defaultValue = 0.1f;

        public Slider()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
        }

        private void sliderControl_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            float bar_size = 0.45f;
            float x = Bar(defaultValue);
            int y = (int)(sliderControl.Height * bar_size);

            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.DimGray, 0, y, sliderControl.Width, y / 2);
        }

        private float Bar(float value)
        {
            return (sliderControl.Width - 24) * (value - Min) / (float)(Max - Min);
        }

        protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnResize(e);

            MaintainPictureBoxSize();
        }

        private void MaintainPictureBoxSize()
        {
            sliderControl.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Normal;

            sliderControl.Location = new Point();
            sliderControl.Size = new Size();

            var clientSize = this.ClientSize;

            if (sliderControl.Image == null)
                sliderControl.Size = clientSize;
            else
            {
                Size s = sliderControl.Image.Size;
                sliderControl.Size = new Size(
                    clientSize.Width > s.Width ? clientSize.Width : s.Width,
                    clientSize.Height > s.Height ? clientSize.Height : s.Height);
            }
        }
    }
}
```